# Android parse time in default timezone

Tags: android, timezone

I want to parse a time value formatted as `"12:34:56"`, which comes from an external web service, to a `Date`, `Calendar` or anything that I can later compare to current time.

The problem is that on Android, `DateFormat.parse` seems to ignore the user's default timezone and parse the value as if it was in UTC. Given this code:

```
DateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
String inTime = "12:34:56";
Date time = timeFormat.parse(inTime);
Date now = new Date();
```

I get the wanted result on my desktop (Java 1.6.0_29):

```
Thu Jan 01 12:34:56 CET 1970
Mon Nov 21 20:53:04 CET 2011
```

In other words, the string "12:34:56" is parsed in the default timezone. However, on Android this seems to be parsed in UTC, because it is one hour off:

```
Thu Jan 01 11:34:56 GMT+0100 1970
Mon Nov 21 20:53:02 GMT+0100 2011
```

I even tried setting the timezone using `timeFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault())`, but this does not help. Is there any way to force `DateFormat.parse` to parse the time in the default (user) timezone on Android, or do I have to convert everything to UTC and back to get it working?

Comment: Is your own timezone one off?

Comment: Yes it is, CET is currently GMT+1, so the timezone information is correct, however the timezone in which the time is parsed is not.

Comment: Hey, how do you print those two outputs, the one with 1970 and the other with 2011? I don't understand how you get the line with the 2011.

Comment: This is the current time. I need to compare the times I get from the webservice with the current time, I do not care about the date. I later use only the hour and minute components to calculate the time span between now and the given time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out my device really had some issues with time-zones. I tried running the code on some other devices and it worked as expected.

I resolved the issue for my phone by installing [TimeZone Fixer](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.force.timezonefixer) and updating the timezone information.

I will leave my code as-is, but I will have to implement some workarounds if the problem turns out to be more common.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem : I just needed to had the Locale to the dateFormatter.
Here is what I've done :

```
public static String getDateAsString(long milliSeconds, String dateFormat)
    {
    // Create a DateFormatter object for displaying date in specified format.
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat, Locale.getDefault());

    // Create a calendar object that will convert the date and time value in milliseconds to date.
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    TimeZone tz = calendar.getTimeZone();
    Date date = new Date(milliSeconds);
    calendar.setTime(date);
    calendar.setTimeZone(tz);
    return formatter.format(calendar.getTime());
}
```

hope it helps !

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```java
Date time = null;
try {
    DateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
    timeFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")); // Add this. "GMT" works too.
    String inTime = "12:34:56";
    time = timeFormat.parse(inTime);
}
catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return;
}

// and print with:

Log.e("Test", "TIIIIME: " + time.toGMTString()); // Not toString...
```

For me this code produces:

> 1 Jan 1970 12:34:56 GMT

Comment: The problem with this approach is that I want to compare this value to the current time, which is in CET, not UTC. Therefore, I want to get 12:34:56 CET from "12:34:56" - which is what I get on my Desktop.

Comment: [Central European Time](http://www.timeanddate.com/library/abbreviations/timezones/eu/cet.html), GMT+1 currently.

Comment: Does it work with `timeFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+01:00"));` as you wished? Or does it have to be generic to the user's own location?

Comment: This works on desktop, but unfortunately does not work on my Android 2.2.1. This seems to be an Android issue. I feel I will have to manually work around this by adjusting the times....

Comment: Okay, now I understand the whole case. I tested with `TimeZone.getDefault()` and it gives me the correct result: "Thu Jan 01 12:34:56 Europe/Helsinki 1970". I wonder why it didn't with your setup? I've got 2.1-update1.

Comment: I find your information disturbing... If my device is "special", I should not rush into ad-hoc solutions... Unfortunately, none of the methods work on my device. I've just tried the emulator, and all methods work as should. I will have to dig deeper into the problem, but thanks for the support.

Comment: All the luck for finding a solution for this. I cannot help more at this time. :/